# Apollo GraphQL: Set null knowing variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to make a request using a query, the response can or cannot have an specific parameter, so is there a way to set that parameter as null and still receive the response

Query

```
query FetchStore {
        storeId
        cartNumber
    }
```

The storeId will always be received but the cartNumber might not be returned, I'm using the version 2 of apollo so this means I can't use the `typePolicies` from v3

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Do you have trouble with the server not returning the data you want? With Apollo not returning the data you want (from its clientside cache)? Or do you have a problem making a query that tells what data you need? Or defining a schema that allows making such queries? Are you talking about field arguments or result properties when you say "parameter"?

Comment: Please share the schema definition (or the relevant parts of it) and the response your api returns for that query.